# Function to calculate time series wise max and min

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, function

I have image collection from that I want to make a loop function where I want to call all images that have the same temporal resolution but date range varies (like 2000-06-09 to 2019-06-17) through the time series and calculates one max and one min for this date range. how to do this?

```
//Image listing
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").filterBounds(table).select('NDVI');

var modis_list = [];
for(var i = 6; i <=10; i++) {
  for(var j = 2000; j <=2019; j++){
    modis_list.push(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year')));
  }
}
print(modis_list);
var modis_filtered_flattened = 
    ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(modis_list).flatten());

 print(modis_filtered_flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. I'm guessing you want imagery for a number of years, but only for certain dates. Then you want the min and max value for each pixel. If so, this could be a way to do that:

```
 var region = Map.getBounds(true)
 var startDate = '2000-06-09'
 var endDate = '2019-06-17'

 var startDayOfYear = ee.Date(startDate).getRelative('day', 'year')
 var endDayOfYear = ee.Date(endDate).getRelative('day', 'year')

 var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
  .filterBounds(region)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(startDayOfYear, endDayOfYear))

var minMax = modis  
  .select('NDVI')
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax())
  .clip(region)

var visParams = {min: 500, max: 9500, palette: 'red,orange,yellow,green'}  
Map.addLayer(minMax.select('NDVI_min'), visParams, 'min')
Map.addLayer(minMax.select('NDVI_max'), visParams, 'max')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c288bb82bcdc5567d97ca38133218487

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your kind help what I want to do it's quite similar to your suggested code.